# How to use the current and also next iteration value inside a ngFor (Angular 4)

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

This is the loop i have.
I need to use the activity object and also the next activity object in a single iteration.Any Thoughts on how to do that ?

```
 *ngFor="let activity of course.activities; let i = index"
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Agree with @Vikas. It would be useful if you could put this in context.

Comment: also provide what does your `course.activities` containes

Comment: So what do you expect to display in the last iteration, because there is no next element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want the last element to be displayed alone

You have to loop only through `course.activities.length - 1`. That is exclude the last item, because that gets displayed as the `next` item of `last but one` item.

```
public course = {activities : [1,2,3]};

<div *ngFor = "let a of course.activities.slice(1); let i = index">
  {{course.activities[i]}}-- {{course.activities[i+1]}}
</div>
```

Loop is required just get the index of an element inside an array

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8pzv1a)

Comment: Thanks alot - Got an idea

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather create chunks of your array, then loop them and just take 0 and 1. For example, to get chunks, you can use (may be different depending on your rxjs version)

```
export function chunk<T>(arr: T[], chunkSize: number): Observable<T[][]> {
  return Observable.from(arr).pipe(bufferCount(chunkSize)).toArray();
}
```

then loop in the template

```
<div *ngFor="let activity of chunkedActivities | async">
    {{ activity[0] }} - {{ activity[1] }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this way seems easy too